# How to solve the problem with "impossible constraint in asm" while building libmfx for ARM?

Tags: c++, build, arm

I have a problem. I'm trying to compile libmfx for ARM v7-a processor from source code. But when I launch "make" I have an error:

[image]

The source code in src/mfx_critical_section_linux.cpp:

```
mfxU32 mfxInterlockedCas32(mfxCriticalSection *pCSection, mfxU32 value_to_exchange, mfxU32 value_to_compare)
{
    mfxU32 previous_value;

    asm volatile ("lock; cmpxchgl %1,%2"
                  : "=a" (previous_value)
                  : "r" (value_to_exchange), "m" (*pCSection), "0" (value_to_compare)
                  : "memory", "cc");
    return previous_value;
}
```

Why does the constraint is impossible? What should I do to resolve the problem?

Comment: Maybe the problem is ARM compiler does not support these assembler code?

Comment: Seems like something you could re-write using [__atomic_compare_exchange](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fatomic-Builtins.html).  More portable, and more maintainable (no one likes supporting inline asm code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lock; cmpxchgl` is x86 assembly code. No surprise really, as libmfx is an Intel library (as in, libmfx was written by the company that makes x86 chips). It really isn't designed to compile on ARM.